# Subquery using Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm, subquery

I have been trying to wrap my head around this but to no avail. The table is as :

```
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |        |
| rating                   | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_id               | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id                  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at               | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_at              | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A user can rate a product multiple times. We do not update the rating but create a new record every time the user rates again for analytics purpose such as to show the trend line etc. Rating is stored as char and has 3 options - G for good, B for bad, N for neutral. So what i am trying to get as output is (just representing in JSON for better readability):

```
{
 { rating:'G',
   no_users_rated: 50
 },
 { rating:'B',
   no_users_rated: 150
 },
 { rating:'N',
   no_users_rated: 20
 }
}
```

I worked out the raw SQL but

- It works on MySQL 5.6 but for 5.7 it fails with the error  - Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Yes i know the cause why this is happening but i was not able to still get it working. Tried putting ANY, EVERY etc aggregate values on the rating field and also a few other things but to no avail. please note that i do not want to change SQL gloabl modes.
- In my quest for fixing the error i came to know about Subquery introduced from Django 1.11 and was wondering if we can do it using Django ORM and subqueries, outer ref  etc? Shouldn't that be the way to go. I did try to form this but was not able to. Have just been able to do this but that too i am not sure.

  latest_records = Subquery(ProductUserRating.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('user_id'), product_id=OuterRef('product_id')).aggregate(Max('created_at')))
  user_products_rating_latest = ProductUserRating.objects.filter(created_at__in=latest_records)

For reference below is the query:

```
 Select rating,  count(user_id) from (
        Select user_id, rating, product_id FROM Table1 n where created_at = 
              (
               select MAX(created_at) from Table1 where user_id = n.user_id 
               and product_id = n.product_id  
              )
    and product_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id, product_id) AS T group by rating;
```

Comment: I don't get it, wouldn't something like that work for you?
 `Rating.objects.values('rating').annotate(no_users_rated=Count('user'))`

Comment: @moenad Thanks for the reply but that is not what i am after. A user can rate the same product multiple times and hence before aggregating we first need to find those records consisting of the product, user, rating by latest time and then sum it across all products and users